# Do I need to disclose my affiliation on non-promotional, technical answers on my project

Tags: discussion, self-promotion, affiliate

As a web search will tell you, I'm a committer on the [Tycho](http://eclipse.org/tycho/) project. This means that I'm affiliated with the project, and according to [the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion), implies that I need to state that affiliation in every Tycho-related answer:

> Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers.

But this really feels wrong: If for example I'd write "I'm a committer" in my answer to a Tycho question with multiple answers, this feels like saying "I'm a committer, so that's why I am right and all others are wrong". IMHO, the affiliation statement would be undermining the community's mechanism for choosing the best answer based on the content of the answers, and not based on ranks and titles. I don't want to get votes because I'm a committer, but only if people like the information I'm providing.

So, for a purely technical answer on a project that I am affiliated with, do I really need to state my affiliation? I'm not promoting my project by answering a question of someone who happened to choose my product, am I?

Comment: I might put it in your profile and only mention it in questions where you're suggesting using Tycho when the question isn't explictly about Tycho. For example "How can I do [thing Tycho does]?"

Comment: You don't trust SO users much, we certainly like to think they vote for content and not people.  You can of course do a simple experiment to check if that's accurate (research is expected :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That blurb about disclosure is really about people taking every opportunity to suggest their project as a solution.

If the *question* is from *someone else* about your project, then no, I don't think you need to add a disclosure to your answer(s). You're not promoting the project; you're just answering a question and have some very specific expertise in that area.

Putting your affiliation in your user profile would be a good thing to do, I think.

Comment: While not necessary, it never hurts to mention your affiliation. In some cases, it could give your answer extra credibility.